# Почему цифры жирным шрифтом?

Tags: вёрстка, шрифты

Для текста выбран один шрифт `Montserrat`, `font-weight:400`, но цифры выделены жирным шрифтом.
Как это исправить?  Или это цифры так прорисованы в этом шрифте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Либо сюда выложите работающий вариант с кодом, либо на сервисы аля cssdeck, jsfiddle и т.п. и ссылку сюда... Гадалки не тут находятся, чтоб по картинках смотреть что у вас так или не так. В самом шрифте этом цифры и буквы одинаковы

Comment: Вы забыли указать гугл-фонтс, что вам нужна кириллица